# Set a twig value with JS

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I've seen many topics about questions like mine, but I can't get any solutions.

I'm using Symfony, and I have a twig template which displays a form.
Imagine that I have this line :

```
{{ form_row(demandeForm.distinction) }}
```

Thanks to this :

```
            ->add('distinction',null, [
                        'label_attr' => array('id' => "distinct_form"),
                        'required' => false,
                        'label' => 'distinction'
                    ])
```

I also have a submit button. My wish is to modify the value of my row "distinction" when the button is clicked (id of the submit button : formDepot).

Here is my code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formDepot').click(function(){
            $('#distinct_form').value('555');
    });
});
```

When I retrieve my datas on submit, I don't have any value in my "distinction".
Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Your title is so misleading...

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're applying the changes on the **label** value, not on the input itself.

`'label_attr' => array('id' => "distinct_form")` and in js : `$('#distinct_form').val('555');`

Change the form builder to this :

```
->add('distinction',
      null,
      [
          'attr' => array('id' => "distinct_form"),
          'required' => false,
          'label' => 'distinction'
      ])
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I agree with you, I've changed this, but it does not seems to work :(

Comment: Why `null` type by the way?

Answer (score 1):

With attr for the field (not the label), you can try
        $('#distinct_form').val('555'); not .value();

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value, instead of getting the value, try this .....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formDepot').click(function(){
        $('#distinct_form').val();
});
```

Comment: He wants to set the value : *My wish is to modify the value of my row "distinction"*

Comment: got it, but first, he needs to check that click event is working or not.

Comment: What do you expect this `$('#distinct_form').val();` to do ?

Comment: if you get value, that means your click event is working, then you can set value.@Cid

Comment: You *get* nothing. This is like typing a variable name. Did you mean `console.log($('#distinct_form').val());` ?

Comment: yes,
        `console.log($('#distinct_form').val());`